# python - how to let others to check info in triple quotes

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing detailed information for each function in a class, and hope when others use my python code, they could check the info for each function, by using something like `help(function_name)`

For example, I have created a python file called **text_preprocess.py**, in this file I have created a class which includes functions.

```
class Preprocess():
    def str_process(self, row_string):
        '''
        This Standford CoreNLP package requires the text input as 1 single string.
        The input annotators are in you command line input.
        :param row_string: The string format input for Standford CoreNLP
        :return: Json format output
        '''

        parsed_json = self.nlp.annotate(row_string, properties={
                   'annotators': self.standford_annotators,
                   'outputFormat': 'json'
               })
        return parsed_json
```

In this function, as you can see the info is within triple quotes.
But I don't know how could other users see this info without looking into my code.

I have checked many solutions online, people use `help(function_name)`, but it seems that they wrote the code through terminal, and then type `help(function_name)`, many of those examples do not have class either. Using `--help` through command line only gives them the parameter descriptions I added through argparse....

So, if I hope others could **check the info of my function without looking into the code**, where and how could they do that?

Comment: Try `pydoc` (or `pydoc3`)?

Comment: pydoc only works for those built-in python elements, won't work for the functions created by me here

Comment: It works just fine for me.  Have you tried it?  You might also look into [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html).

Comment: if pydoc works fine for you, could you tell me how did you get the info in my `str_process` function? I tried that, it only tells python built-in elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either be in the same directory as your script, or make sure your script is in one of the directories listed in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) (usually, the first option is easier for simple things, but if you want to do the second, [use a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one/) rather than trying to install the module system-wide).
2. Run `pydoc3 text_preprocess` to get documentation for the whole module.  This recursively includes all of the items below the module, such as classes, their members, and functions.
3. Run `pydoc3 text_preprocess.Preprocess` if you just want the class.
4. Run `pydoc3 text_preprocess.Preprocess.str_process` if you just want the method.
5. Use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/index.html) if you want nicely-formatted HTML or other formats such as PDF.

You may also want to remove that empty line at the beginning of your docstring; some docstring-parsing code may misinterpret it.

Answer (score 0):

Putting triple quoted strings just below the declaration of a class or method is called documentation. You can read this using `Preprocess.str_process.__doc__`.

Comment: I tried to run this through terminal, under the same folder of my code file text_preprocess.py, but it is showing "Preprocess.str_process.__doc__: command not found". Do you know where should I run this?

Comment: @Cherry_Wu This will only work within a Python script. It is not a terminal command explicitly. You have to import the module via Python within the terminal and type this with Python.