# yum install python-tkinter without sudo

Tags: python, tkinter, yum

When I try to install `Tkinter` on `Centos` like this:

```
yum install python-tkinter
```

It says:`'You need to be root to perform this command'`.

then I try this :

```
sudo yum install python-tkinter
```

It installed. The problem: It is installed for `python2.6.6` but I want to install it for `python2.7`.

*For example*:

```
$python

Python 2.7.6
```

--

```
$sudo python

Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: Which centos are you using? The package will be matched to the version of centos and i think 6.x will use py2.6. So one easy way would be to upgrade your centos.

Comment: Run `which python` and then check whether you have python 2.7 installed.

Comment: I suggest migrating this question to https://unix.stackexchange.com. Since it not about programming.

Comment: which python : python2.7 and I use Centos 6.8

Comment: `which` should return path to executable.