# Getting long error trying to upgrade Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run

```
pip install -U Django
```

but I'm getting a super long error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py', '/var/folders/vw/5tw6gm0x6tn654xbwq1l698h0000gn/T/pip-yMgDg2-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/vw/5tw6gm0x6tn654xbwq1l698h0000gn/T/pip-yMgDg2-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.pyc', '/var/folders/vw/5tw6gm0x6tn654xbwq1l698h0000gn/T/pip-yMgDg2-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/vw/5tw6gm0x6tn654xbwq1l698h0000gn/T/pip-yMgDg2-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/_
```

it keeps going...

how do i fix this?

Comment: Try running with `sudo` or in a virtual environment

Comment: @ChristopherSu sudo doesn't work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)