# Add package to specific install of Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, apt-get, xmltodict

I am trying to add xmltodict package to Python on Linux.

I have 2 installations of Python on my Linux build; Python 2.7 (default) and Python 3.5 (in the form of an Anaconda installation).  I want to add xmltodict to the Python 3 installation, but when I use `sudo apt-get install python-xmltodict` it adds it to the default Python 2.7 installation.

How can I get apt to add this package to my Python 3 installation without changing the default or using pip? I do not want to have to rebuild my installation with a virtual environment either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: I don't want a virtual environment on my machine, I just want to add the package to a specific install

Comment: well that's misguided.

Comment: Be that as it may, it's my machine, and I don't want to do it.

Comment: Since noone has packaged python-xmltodict for Python 3 on Ubuntu or Debian you cannot add it with apt-get. If you are using something other than Ubuntu or Debian, tell us - perhaps someone has created a a python-xmltodict package for Python 3 on that distro - Are you open to other suggestions than using apt-get ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of why I can't install with apt-get.  I'm open to any suggestions, in fact the more the better because then I have a range of options if I run into this issue again and some of the suggestions don't work for whatever reason!  But the less fiddling with files they require the better - all I'm trying to to do is add a single package, a job for which I don't believe an entire reworking of my system is required.  My Linux build is Ubuntu

Comment: VE is the way to go, if you don't know or want to use it, choose the correct pip binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `conda` for the installation

```
conda install -c conda-forge xmltodict=0.11.0
```

This should work

Comment: Wasn't down-voted by me... you're answer works nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it with pip or easy-install, you can run pip2/pip2.7 and install it. It will be installed for Python which was used to run pip...