# Incompatible libpng versions when running matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, libpng

I'm trying to use facebook research's Detectron. When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.6.21 but running with 1.5.12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/infer_simple.py", line 147, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "tools/infer_simple.py", line 139, in main
    kp_thresh=2
  File "/home/sid/DETECTRON/detectron/lib/utils/vis.py", line 391, in vis_one_image
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(output_dir, '{}'.format(output_name)), dpi=dpi)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1834, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2267, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2595, in print_pdf
    file.finalize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 595, in finalize
    self.writeImages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 1430, in writeImages
    ob.id, smaskObject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 1416, in _writeImg
    self._writePng(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 1366, in _writePng
    _png.write_png(data, buffer)
RuntimeError: Could not create write struct
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know where the application is finding the `libpng 1.5.12` version. I could not find it in my system. I installed `libpng16-16`. It still gives me the same error. I tried out other solutions suggested on the platform but they didn't work

Comment: How did you install matplotlib?

Comment: @code_onkel `pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you `sudo pip` installed matplotlib and that the libpng version that is shipped with the `manylinux` installation package of matplotlib is confused with the libpng version that was installed by `apt`. I recommend using matplotlib inside a [virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one).

```
# create venv
virtualenv ~/matplotlib-venv

# activate venv
source ~/matplotlib-venv/bin/activate

# install matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
pip install <everything else you need>

# run your script
python ~/path/to/your/srcript.py
```