# PyCharm does not run – Project Interpreter problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, module, pycharm

First of all, I want to note that I've read a lot of links related to my problem.
I have some problems with running the code when I want to import a module.

Here is an example of the code:

```
import numpy as np
```

Then PyCharm gives me an exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/Alexander 1
>   2/PycharmProjects/Coursera/Week1/Vectors/Vecors.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import numpy as np
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have read [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html#view) and did all what was written. However, it hasn't been working. I've reloaded the PyCharm – no result.

[image: screenshot that proves that I chose Project Interpreter]

Help me, please! I'm using MacOS 10.13.5, PyCharm 2018.1.4 CE.

Comment: How did you install numpy?

Comment: I installed numpy via pip. All works correctly when I use the terminal instead of PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

You probably have created a new project using virtualenv, read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one).
It basically creates a new project specific environment, so the libraries inside won't cause a conflict with python2 and python3 packages. So, inside Pycharm, open terminal by pressing `alt+f12` , which will open a terminal inside Pycharm, and install numpy usually by `pip install numpy`

Comment: I did what you said and it answered me 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.14.5)

So, unfortunately, it did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I rebooted the computer and created a new project, this problem has disappeared.