# Python on RaspberryPi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have both Python2 and Python3 installed on my raspberry 3.
I am using Python3.
 
Do I have to keep the Python2 or can I remove it. (how?)
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You **absolutely** need to keep Python 2. It is essential for numerous linux system processes. It is highly recommended **not to modify/delete it**.

Btw, you can still try to remove it but you should be prepared for unexpected bahaviours.

Answer (score 2):

Python2 is needed by other libraries in your raspberry. You should keep it.

Now, this doesn't solve your problem, you have 2 python versions and you might be using both python 3 and python 2 libraries simultaneously.

Fortunately, `Virtualenv` is specifically designed for this type of problems.

**VirtualEnv**

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

[What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not remove Python 2 from Raspberry Pi, if you are using Python 3.

(My setup: Raspberry Pi 3, OpenCV 3, Python 3)