# Need to downgrade version of pandas but I'm getting a "ModuleNotFoundError" error

Tags: python, pandas

The error I'm receiving is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.internals.managers'; 
'pandas.core.internals' is not a package
```

I am trying to downgrade my pandas version to version 0.22.0 after having a newer version installed previously. I read that it is an issue with the pickle file, but I'm not sure what this means. How can I update my pickle file so that I can use pandas 0.22.0 after having a newer version installed previously? I need to downgrade so I can assign multiple axes to an axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

[What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Virtualenv is a an isolated python environment you can use for your projects. That way, you can have several versions of whatever packages you want installed.

Install virtualenv with `pip install virtualenv`

Now go to your project directory and run `virtualenv venv`. This creates a folder called venv, which contains an isolated python environment. You can activate it by running `source ./venv/bin/activate`

Now, whatever packages you install will be installed to this virtualenv rather than your original python install.

Comment: thank you for the response! does this virtualenv work well with eclipse?

Comment: You might have to do some configuration to get it working with IDEs. But most popular ones should already be covered in detail over the net.

Comment: But once you figure out how to do it, you'll find it well worth the effort.