# Why should the  (huggingface) Transformers library be installed on a virtual environment?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

In the [huggingface github](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers#installation) it is written:

> You should install  Transformers in a virtual environment. If you're
> unfamiliar with Python virtual environments, check out the user guide.
>
> Create a virtual environment with the version of Python you're going
> to use and activate it.
>
> Now, if you want to use  Transformers, you can install it with pip.
> If you'd like to play with the examples, you must install it from
> source.

Why should it be installed in a virtual python environment?
What are the advantages of doing that rather than installing it on python as is?

Comment: Using virtual environments per project is generally a good practice in Python, nothing special about that library.

Comment: This is true of basically *all* libraries. You want to work in virtual envs for all Python work you do, so that you don't screw with the system install of Python, and so that you don't have a big global list of hundreds of packages that have nothing to do with each other and that may have conflicting requirements.

Comment: Apart from that, using a virtual environment for your project also means that it is easily deployable to a different machine, because all the dependencies are self-contained and can be packaged up in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing up the comments in a community answer:

It's not needed to install huggingface Transformers in a virtual environment, it can be installed just like any other package though there are advantages of using a virtual environment, and is considered a good practice.

- You want to work in virtual envs for all Python work you do, so that you don't interfere the system install of Python, and so that you don't have a big global list of hundreds of packages that have nothing to do with each other and that may have conflicting requirements.
- Apart from that, using a virtual environment for your project also means that it is easily deployable to a different machine, because all the dependencies are self-contained and can be packaged up in one go.

[More in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: I would add that you will often have multiple different projects with different package version requirements. Isolating your environments for each project becomes almost essential in this case.