# How to install python module local to a single project

Tags: python, pip

I've been going around but was not able to find a definitive answer...
So here's my question..

I come from javascript background. I'm trying to pickup python now.
In javascript, the basic practice would be to `npm install` (or use yarn)
This would install some required module in a specific project.

Now, for python, I've figured out that `pip install` is the module manager. 
I can't seem to figure out how to install this specific to a project (like how javascript does it)
Instead, it's all global.. I've found `--user` flag, but that's not really I'm looking for.

I've come to conclusion that this is just a complete different schema and I shouldn't try to approach as I have when using javascript.
However, I can't really find a good document why this method was favored.
It may be just my problem but I just can't not think about how I'm consistently bloating my pip global folder with modules that I'm only ever gonna use once for some single project.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41972261/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.) Anaconda (the simplest) Just download “Anaconda” that contains a lots of python modules pre installed just use them and it also has code editors. You can creat multiple module collections with the GUI.

B.) Venv = virtual environments (if you need something light and specific that contains specific packages for every project

macOS terminal commands:

- Install venv
  `pip install virtualenv`
- Setup Venve (INSIDE BASE Project folder)
  `python3 -m venv thenameofyourvirtualenvironment`
- Start Venve
  `source thenameofyourvirtualenvironment/bin/activate`
- Stop Venve
  `deactivate`
- while it is activated you can install specific packages ex.: 
  `pip -q install bcrypt`

C.) Use “Docker” it is great if you want to go in depth and have a solide experience, but it can get complicated.

Answer (score 0):

`Pip` is a program used to manage Python distribution. You usually have one system distribution which is by default managed by Pip. When you do `pip install scipy`, you install package `scipy` to your system Python. Everytime you try to `import scipy` after it will work because your system Python has it.

Project specific distributions are acomplished by using virtual environments. `python -m venv env` or `venv env` creates a copy of system Python interpreter, pip, setuptools and a couple of other essential tools. In other words, virtual environment created this way is *empty*.

To use created virtual environement one should use `source env/bin/activate`. After that, everytime you invoke `python` command it will use *activated* Python interpreter. When you install packages using pip, it will install them in the virtual environment rather than to your system python. To use system Python again use `deactivate`.

Such usage is actually prefered for projects because some user applications could rely on system Python and some packages, and installing, updating etc. could be potentionally dangerous.

Further reading: [venv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)