# What is the meaning of environment of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have 3 questions:
1. What is the meaning of environment of Anaconda? What is the difference between the usage of enviroment and normal python? 
2. When I use pip install xxx, can I import xxx under a conda environment? When I use conda install xxx, can I import xxx under the normal python interpreter?
3. If I use conda install xxx in env A, can I import xxx when I programme in env B?

Comment: [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41972261/1324033)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda helps you with your virtual environment, makes it easier to use. There is no big differnce between vanila python. But you can use only Anacoda without vanila python installed on your computer and by using virtual environment, you avoid trash files that can interrupt your future programms.