# Why in web-development using flask in python its important to use virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-venv

What if there is problem in setting virtual environment, if we start working without setting it what are the cons for that.

```
PS C:\Users\USER\flaask\enrollment> py -m venv venv
PS C:\Users\USER\flaask\enrollment> venv\scripts\activate
venv\scripts\activate : File C:\Users\USER\flaask\enrollment\venv\scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is        
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ venv\scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: While the question is asking about Flask and "web development", the answer to why use a virtual env is applicable to any Python project. If this question wants to be specific to Flask or "web development", it needs to give details on how the web app is deployed (ex. if it's running inside a Python version-specific container, don't need a virtual env).