# How to remove Python 2.7 from Mac?

Tags: python

I am having troubles removing Python 2.7 from my Mac. I have tried to install both Python 3.8 and 3.9, but when I run "python --version" in Terminal it says 2.7.16.

How can I uninstall 2.7?

Comment: Wich version of Mac OS are you running? And how did you install python?

Comment: You almost certainly should **not** do this. macOS comes with a version of Python that it needs. Don't mess with your OS. Instead, use virtualenvs for your projects.

Comment: use `python3` instead of `python` command, removing python 2 can cause problems

Comment: Thanks, I will tryt o use python3 instead of python

Comment: ...but [still use virtualenvs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41972261/354577).

Comment: I faced the same issue, better create a Virtual Environment with the python version you prefer. And work on it.

Comment: you need to remove python2.7 and the links to it and paths. this is described/solved in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4