# Does this mean i have two installations of python? Should i delete the global one? I only use conda enviroment

Tags: python, anaconda

[This is very confusing for a newbie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nf74.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: you can select whichever one you wish to use. I do tend to remove older versions for good measure if i am not using them and just use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Everything here looks normal. That global one appears to be the macOS system installation - leave it alone, don't use it or try to delete. For each project or project-type create a Conda environment.